# Android SQLiteDatabase rawQuery RunTimeException (on SELECT Statement)

Tags: android, sqlite

So I have looked at other rawQuery problems and I believe I'm using the correct syntax in a query that should return the value of Strength corresponding to a particular ID. The mehod that is throwing the exception is at the bottom of the code, called `getStrength()`.

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private static final String DATABASE_NAME="CharacterData";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION= 1;
private static final String Table_Name="ProfileData";

//have two columns to test
private static final String KEY_ID = "ID";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
private static final String KEY_STR ="Strength";
private static final String KEY_DEX ="Dexterity";
private static final String KEY_CONST ="Constitution";
private static final String KEY_INT="Intelligence";
private static final String KEY_WIS ="Wisdom";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

    String CREATE_TABLE_DATA="CREATE TABLE "+ Table_Name+ "("+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+ KEY_NAME +
            " TEXT, " + KEY_STR+ " INTEGER, "+KEY_DEX+" INTEGER, " +KEY_CONST+ " INTEGER, " +KEY_INT+ " INTEGER, "+ KEY_WIS+ " INTEGER)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DATA);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_Name);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
public void insert(int id, String name,int Str,int Dex,int Const ,int Int, int Wis){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID,id);
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
    values.put(KEY_STR, Str); // strength
    values.put(KEY_DEX, Dex); // dexterity
    values.put(KEY_CONST, Const); // Constitution
    values.put(KEY_INT, Int); // Intelligence
    values.put(KEY_WIS, Wis); // Name
    db.insert(Table_Name, null, values);
    db.close();

}
public String read(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor= db.query(Table_Name, new String []{KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,KEY_STR,KEY_DEX,KEY_CONST,KEY_INT,KEY_WIS}, KEY_ID+ "=?", new String []{String.valueOf(id)},
            null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor!=null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer();
    sb= sb.append(cursor.getString(0)+" ");
    sb=sb.append(cursor.getString(1)+" ");
    sb=sb.append(cursor.getString(2)+" ");
    sb=sb.append(cursor.getString(3)+" ");
    sb=sb.append(cursor.getString(4)+" ");
    sb=sb.append(cursor.getString(5)+" ");
    sb=sb.append(cursor.getString(7)+" ");
    String exit= sb.toString();
    return exit;

}
public int getStrength(int id){
    int str=0;
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    if(db==null){
        return 0;
    }
    //
    // Cursor cursor=db.query(Table_Name,new String[]{"Strength"},"Strength like "+"'" + id+"'", null,null,null,null);
    String[] args={"1"};
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT Strength FROM ProfileData WHERE ID LIKE = ?",args);
    while(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        str=cursor.getInt(0);

    }
    cursor.close();

    return str;
     }
  }
```

The error message i am getting:

```
 E/SQLiteLog: (1) near   "=": syntax error

 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT Strength FROM ProfileData WHERE ID LIKE = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you query from,

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT Strength FROM ProfileData WHERE ID LIKE = ?", args);
```

to,

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT Strength FROM ProfileData WHERE ID = ?", args);
```